# How to Implement Firebase Project to another Account?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Download a project from github in which firebase is used for authentication and Database. I have no access to that database but i want to make some changes to that firebase account. Can i transfer one project (Having no access to that account) to a new Firebase

Comment: Yes, you can move the code to use a different Firebase project. Somewhere in the project you downloaded is a reference to the Firebase project it connects to. Find that reference (we can't tell you how without seeing the project), and update it with the data for your own Firebase project.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you mean to say that i should remove the jason file from the project and paste a new jason file for the latest firebase account ??

Comment: That depends on how the app connects to its Firebase project. If it does so (only) through a `google-services.json`, then you can indeed make it connect to a different project by using your own `google-services.json`. But it's hard for us to say how that works for your project. I **highly** recommend first getting more comfortable with Firebase by for example taking the codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/

Comment: okay thanks buddy i will let you know if i do it